# Retrieving data from couchdb using Couchrest model takes more time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, couchdb, couchrest

In my project we are using couch rest and couchdb. We have written views as well in the model to retrieve data. But it takes more time to fetch data even the data count is around 15k

For ex:

```
Class Model < CouchRest::Model::Base
  view :by_some_id_and_timestamp "function (doc) {
    if ((doc['duplicated'] !== true)  && doc.type == 'SomeType') { 
      emit([doc.some_id, doc.timestamp], 1);
    }
  }"
end


Model.by_some_id_and_timestamp.startkey([some_id, timestamp]).endkey([some_id, timestamp]).docs
```

The result contains around 15k records and it takes hardly 3 to 5 mins to fetch.

Kindly suggest me.

Comment: Have you attempted to paginate your results? Or maybe make batch request? If you query this view from curl and dump the result into a file, does it takes 3-5 minutes?

Comment: Query this view and assign it to a variable would take this much time. And am not going to display the results in any page, so pagination not required on my scenario. How to execute in batch wise?

Comment: Basically, you can query X documents until you get all of them. You can use the skip or a combination of the limit and startkey_docid.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. Manipulation with records not taking more time. Only querying X documents take more time.